# Python extract 3 words before and 3 words after a specific list of words with a regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to use python to extract 3 words before and 3 words after a specific list of words

> Nokia Lumia 930 Smartphone, Display 5 pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB
>   RAM, Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, Windows Phone 8.1,
>   Bianco [Germania]

At the moment I'm using this regex without success

```
((?:[\S,]+\s+){0,3})ram\s+((?:[\S,]+\s*){0,3})
```

https://regex101.com/r/yN6iI0/1

My list of words that I need is:

- Display
- Fotocamera
- RAM
- Processore
- Memoria

Comment: What do you mean with extract? It could really help us if you provide an *input/output example*

Comment: So, does [`((?:\S+\s+){0,3})(Display|Fotocamera|RAM|Processore|Memoria)\s+((?:\S+\s*){0,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8fM5/1) work for you?

Comment: Provide your expected output.

Comment: Yes it works well... why ((?:\S+\s+){0,3})RAM\s+((?:\S+\s*){0,3}) doesn't work?

Comment: I need to specific the items in the list one by one

Comment: @UsiUsi: I explained why in my answer, and suggested some improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex did not work because `\s+` requires at least 1 whitespace, but between `RAM` and `,` there is none. Either use a `*` quantifier or just remove it and use ``

```
(?i)((?:\S+\s+){0,3})\bRAM\b\s*((?:\S+\s+){0,3})
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK7uB3/2)

I added `\b` (word boundary) to make sure we match `RAM`, not `RAMBUS`.

Mind the `re.I` modifier (or use an inline version `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern).

Other patterns can be formed in a similar way, just replace `RAM` with the words from your list.

Comment: I see you do not need the version with alternation, I just kept the one that can be used once at a time.

Comment: Yes, thank you this regex seems to work very well... Thank you so much... I'm testing another solution proposed (the one with the comma) before choosing the best answer :)
Thank you dear!

Comment: Just note that `,?` means *1 or 0 commas*, but what if there are other punctuation symbols? I think word boundary is key here, and whitespace should be optional. If you want to match any non-word character (optionally) after `ram`, you can use `\W*` instead of `,?` suggested by vks. See [this demo: `(?i)((?:\S+\s+){0,3})\bRAM\b\W*((?:\S+\s+){0,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/kK7uB3/3). This looks more generic.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:[\S,]+\s+){0,3})ram,?\s+((?:[\S,]+\s*){0,3})

                       ^^
```

Just add a `,`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yN6iI0/4

You can use this finally,

```
((?:[\S,]+\s+){0,3})(?:ram|Display|Fotocamera|RAM|Processore|Memoria),?\s+((?:[\S,]+\s*){0,3})
```

Comment: what does it mean the comma after ram?

Comment: @UsiUsi you had `,` in your input string so to match that you give `,?`.the `?` is fir cases where `,` is not present