# Regex return X words before and after the match recursive

Tags: python, regex

This approach works perfect [get 3 words before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848408/python-extract-3-words-before-and-3-words-after-a-specific-list-of-words-with-a)

But if the match is inside of that range, rest is ignored [get 6 words before and after DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kK7uB3/13) return just one match instead of 2.

Expected output

```
full match 1: 5 pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB RAM RAM Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, 

full match 2: pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB RAM RAM Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, Windows
```

Its just giving match 1

Comment: Okay, thank you. What do you suggest to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this approach using `re.finditer`:

```
>>> s = 'Nokia Lumia 930 Smartphone, Display 5 pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB RAM RAM Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, Windows Phone 8.1, Bianco [Germania]'
>>> regex = r"\s*\bRAM\b(?=\s*((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S+))"
>>> for m in re.finditer(regex, s):
...     print ( re.findall(r'((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S+)$', s[1:m.start()])[0], m.group(1) )
...
```

```
('5 pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB', 'RAM Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB,')
('pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB RAM', 'Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, Windows')
```

---

If you want full matches only then use:

```
>>> for m in re.finditer(regex, s):
...     print ( re.findall(r'((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S+)$', s[1:m.start()])[0] + m.group(1) )
...
```

```
5 pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GBRAM Processore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB,
pollici, Fotocamera 20 MP, 2GB RAMProcessore Quad-Core 2,2GHz, Memoria 32GB, Windows
```

Comment: Thank you sir for sharing solution sir, could you please explain more on `print ( re.findall(r'((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S+)$', s[1:m.start()])[0], m.group(1) )` part please, will be grateful to you sir, specially `s[1:m.start()])[0], m.group(1)` part in it sir.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. `re.findall(r'((?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S+)$', s[1:m.start()])` matches last 6 words in a string in string that is extracted using substring of `s` from position `1` to `m.start()` where `m` is the result of `finditer`